# Why are parameters in array functions are in different order than in string functions?

Tags: php

I was always wondering why in PHP array function we have `$needle` before the `$haystack` and vice versa in string functions. E.g.:

```
mixed array_search ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = false ] )
bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )

string strstr ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, bool $before_needle = false ] )
int strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
```

Is it another PHP sadness or there is some sort of logical explanation for this?
The thing is I often can't remember which one is in what order - maybe that logic beyond this will help.

Comment: This is another PHP sadness! Even in array functions no specific convension was not followed. see the manual of [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Yip, just one of those PHP things, very little "formalization". Things like this always bug me. My worst one yet is `nl2br()`. It's like a teenage girl named that function

Comment: Functions like `strstr` are inspired by C and the parameter order matches that. Consistency with the rest of PHP was clearly less important then. (Get a proper IDE with parameter hinting to take care of this problem.)

Comment: Yup, it has to do with the libc naming.  Rasmus explains it here: https://youtu.be/6uodrhwUXFM?t=1149

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a php sadness that was introduced in the early versions of the language and never corrected to avoid such a BC breack.
It is the first reason people invoke when they criticise php